# The longest cycle in an undirected graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, cycle

How i can get the longest cycle in a undirected Graph (without BackTracking, it takes too long).

Example:

```
0 3 0 1 0
3 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Solve: 3 + 3 + 1 => Out: 1 - 2 - 3 - 1.

Comment: If you could find the longest cycle in a graph in polynomial time you would also solve the hamiltonian cycle problem in polynomial time, which is known to be a pretty hard problem. How big is your input, i.e. how many vertices, edges are in your graph?

Comment: Is that an adjacency matrix? If so, what is the '3' doing there - do you have colored edges? Also, vertices 3 and 5 are disconnected?

Answer (score 4):

If you can find the longest cycle, you can detect whether the graph has a Hamiltonian Cycle, which is an NP-complete problem, thus making your problem NP-hard.

That means no solution will be fundamentally better than backtracking unless P=NP.